# Integrating $g: ℝ^2\to ℝ$ - Order of Integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

The problem:

[image: Math problem]

My work:

[image: My work]

I found the two integrals to be equal to each other, which is clearly not the desired result. Any suggestions/pointers? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is in doing/thinking $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$, not $\int_0^\infty$.

For the latter integral, you should have
$$\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty g(x,y)\,dy\,dx = \int_0^1\int_0^x\,dy\,dx + \int_1^2\int_0^x g(x,y)\,dy\,dx + \int_2^\infty\int_0^x g(x,y)\,dy\,dx.$$
The first integral gives you $1/2$, the second gives you $1/2$, and the last gives you $0$.

Comment: Can you give more explanation? I don't understand how you came up with the bounds for the integrals.

Comment: Draw the lines in the region $\{(x,y): y\ge 0\}$, and mark or shade in different colors where $g=0$, $g=1$, and $g=-1$. Then draw vertical lines corresponding to the possible $x$ intervals: $x\le 0$, $0\le x\le 1$, $1\le x\le 2$, and finally $x\ge 2$.

Comment: Thanks. Are the bounds for my first integral correct, or is it just by luck that I got the first integral to equal zero?

Comment: The first one is right. The picture I suggested you draw should help you see this.

Answer (score 2):

$\int_0^\infty g(x,y) dy = \begin{cases} 0, & x <0 \\
x, & x \in [0,1] \\
2-x, & x \in (1,2] \\
0, & x> 0 \end{cases}$.

Hence $\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty g(x,y) dy dx = 1$.

**Note**: The picture below shows the relevant areas in $[0,\infty)^2$ where $g$ takes the values $\pm 1$. Now integrate along a vertical line.

[image]

Comment: Can you give more explanation? I don't understand how you came up with that piecewise function.

Comment: I have added a picture which explains the value of the integral.